# Fastest way of converting IPv6 dotted format string to colon format ? C#

Tags: c#, ipv6, ipv4

What is the fastest way of converting the dotted format of the following IP from version 6 
to colon format??

128.91.45.157.220.40.101.10.10.1.252.87.22.200.31.255

I just typed the IP above randomly.

Thanks

Comment: Not tested: `IPAdress.Parse(YourIP).ToString()`

Comment: @TimSchmelter: IPAddress.Parse does not support weird custom formats like "IPv6 dotted format".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var result = new IPAddress(x.Split('.').Select(byte.Parse).ToArray()).ToString();
// result == "805b:2d9d:dc28:650a:a01:fc57:16c8:1fff"
```

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way would be to do all parsing and conversion yourself.

This is more than ten times faster than the currently accepted answer using `Split`, `Select` and `IPAddress`:

```
string ip = "128.91.45.157.220.40.101.10.10.1.252.87.22.200.31.255";
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(8 * 4 + 7);
string hex = "0123456789abcdef";
int pos = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  int n = 0;
  while (pos < ip.Length && ip[pos] != '.') {
    n = n * 10 + (ip[pos++] - '0');
  }
  pos++;
  b.Append(hex[n / 16]);
  b.Append(hex[n % 16]);
  if (i % 2 == 1 && i < 15) {
    b.Append(':');
  }
}
return b.ToString();
```

Note: This code does not omit leading zeroes, it always produces a string with eight four-digit values.

#### Edit:

This is the times per operation that I get from running each a million times:

```
Fast: 0,00038 ms.
Linq: 0,00689 ms.
```

Comment: Please don't forget to add time to debug potential bugs in a newly created code rather than widely tested, stable, standards-compliant code. If you gain, what, thousands of a second and get 5 hours of downtime in return, what's the point?

Comment: @Wajih: I added the times above.

Comment: @ssg: Yes, naturally it takes longer to get faster code. I don't see what you mean by "standards-compliant" code though? What standard would this code not comply to?

Comment: @Guffa: I don't know because your code does not include unit tests or specs. But what I know is that `IPAddress` class is standards-compliant. More ad-hoc code means more maintenance. I appreciate the effort to get the fastest code though. I'm just pointing out that it may not always be a time saver to use the "fastest" code.

Comment: @ssg: What do you **mean** by "standards-compliant"? What standard are you referring to?

Comment: @ssg - If you are going to complain that "parse it yourself" code is not as standards compliant as a library class IPAddress, then you have to reject this entire question.  "IPv6 dotted notation" is not standards compliant, yet is the whole point of this question and Guffa's answer.

Comment: @Guffa I thought dotted notation would have an RFC for it. Apparently it doesn't. But my comments regarding "fastest is not always the fastest 'code'" stands. The time developers spending understanding internal mechanics here has a potential of creating more overhead.

Comment: @JesseChisholm I was actually arguing with the question asked. OP definitely missed the "time spent on debugging ad-hoc code" part. What's wrong about pointing that out?

Comment: @ssg: Still, after a year thinking about it? ;)

Comment: @Guffa Jesse triggered my memories :)

Comment: @Guffa - Once something is on the Internet, it never dies. :) I just got reminded by StackExchange about this thread and that I hadn't commented on it in awhile. :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no official 'dotted' format for IPv6. The string you show is not a valid IPv6 address... Please stick to the official formats and follow RFC 4291 and if possible the recommendations in RFC 5952. Using other formats will cause confusion and interoperability problems.